# How can I append two lists in sequential order in python?

Tags: python, append, sequential

I have a list of coordinates and another list of height values. How can I append height values to coordinate list in sequential order?

```
coor = [[[83.75, 18.70], [57.50, 18.70], [57.5, 2.87], [83.75, 4.18]],
   [[83.75, 34.54], [110.0, 35.0], [104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59]],
   [[104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59], [83.75, 4.18], [100.0, 5.0]],
   [[-5.0, 33.0], [18.12, 33.40],[18.12, 16.70],[-2.53, 16.70]], 
   [[18.12, 16.70],[-2.53, 16.70], [0.0, 0.0],[18.12, 0.90]]]
height = [5,4,5,6,6]
```

expected result:

```
result = [[[83.75, 18.70], [57.50, 18.70], [57.5, 2.87], [83.75, 4.18],5],
   [[83.75, 34.54], [110.0, 35.0], [104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59],4],
   [[104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59], [83.75, 4.18], [100.0, 5.0],5],
   [[-5.0, 33.0], [18.12, 33.40],[18.12, 16.70],[-2.53, 16.70],6], 
   [[18.12, 16.70],[-2.53, 16.70], [0.0, 0.0],[18.12, 0.90],6]]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tldr: One line solution, **zip** the iterables ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)) and list for desired output explanation below:

```
[list(item) for item in list(zip(coor,height))]
```

explanation:

```
list1 = [ 
    [['a','a'],['aa','aa']], 
     [['b','b'],['bb','bb']]]
list2 = [1,2]

for item in list(zip(list1,list2)): 
    print('zip output', item) 
    print('desired output', list(item))
```

Output:

```
zip output ([['a', 'a'], ['aa', 'aa']], 1)
desired output [[['a', 'a'], ['aa', 'aa']], 1]
zip output ([['b', 'b'], ['bb', 'bb']], 2)
desired output [[['b', 'b'], ['bb', 'bb']], 2]
```

as one line list comprehension :

```
[list(item) for item in list(zip(list1,list2))]
```

Output:

```
[[[['a', 'a'], ['aa', 'aa']], 1], [[['b', 'b'], ['bb', 'bb']], 2]]
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer so other can learn **how** it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind tuples, you can just use `zip`

```
> list(zip(coor, height))

[([[83.75, 18.7], [57.5, 18.7], [57.5, 2.87], [83.75, 4.18]], 5),
 ([[83.75, 34.54], [110.0, 35.0], [104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59]], 4),
 ...
```

If it must be a list use `zip` in a comprehension.

```
> [list(pair) for pair in zip(coor, height)]

[[[83.75, 18.7], [57.5, 18.7], [57.5, 2.87], [83.75, 4.18]], 5],
[[[83.75, 34.54], [110.0, 35.0], [104.86, 19.59], [83.75, 19.59]], 4],
...
```